# Use SQL to Extract Month and Year from double in SQLite Database

Tags: sql, sqlite, strftime

I need to extract the month and year as integers from `GivingDate`.  `GivingDate` is a C++ `TDateTime` stored as a `double` in the SQLite database for correct sorting purposes.  However, `strftime` requires the date as a `string` argument.

Here is the SQL statement (that doesn't work):

```
SELECT 
  GivingDate, 
  Amount, 
  strftime('%y', datetime(GivingDate, 'unixepoch')) as GivingYear,
  strftime('%m', datetime(GivingDate, 'unixepoch')) as GivingMonth 
FROM 
  FSBC_GivingInfo;
```

How can I revise the SQL statement to extract the month and year as `GivingMonth` and `GivingYear` from `GivingDate` in an SQLite database?

Comment: What is `TDateTime`? Is it really the number of seconds since 1970?

Comment: TDateTime is the Windows system time.  Time '0' is 12/30/1899 12:00 am.  The integer part represents the day since 12/30/1899 12:00 am and the fraction part represents the fraction of a 24 hour day.

Answer (score 1):

If you're storing the timestamps as TDateTime in the database, you have to transform it first.  For example:

```
SQLite version 3.15.1 2016-11-04 12:08:49
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite> create table x(timestamp real);
sqlite> insert into x values (2.75);
sqlite> insert into x values(35065);
sqlite> select * from x;
2.75
35065.0
sqlite> select strftime('%J', '1899-12-30'); -- base time as a Julian Day Number
2415018.5
sqlite> select datetime(timestamp+2415018.5) from x;
1900-01-01 18:00:00
1996-01-01 00:00:00
select cast(strftime('%m', timestamp+2415018.5) as integer), cast(strftime('%d', timestamp+2415018.5) as integer) from x;
1|1
1|1
sqlite>
```

But, it would better to store your timestamps in one of the formats listed in https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

(I suggest either the Julian Date or the 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format - both will sort correctly)

Answer (score -1):

I do not know how to create your sql tables, but the data in sql is in date time format.You can edit it later :
first get your datetime to c++.then edit in code.

```
DateTime myDateTime = "your  sql datetime";
string sqlFormattedDate = myDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
```

Comment: "You can edit it later : first get your datetime to c++ then edit in code."  That won't work for me because I need to use "GROUP BY GivingYear" and "GROUP BY Giving Month" in subsequent SQL statements.